# Comment Mixin for Django. Why is CommentPost defined like this?

Tags: django, forms, mixins

I am a beginner in Django, and I was reading WS Vincent's Django for beginners. In the second to last chapter, he writes the following code. He's creating a view that allows for comments that can handle GET and POST requests without mixing FormMixin and his created ArticleDetailView. I understand all of that, but what I don't understand is why it was constructed like this? Can someone explain what self.object and self.get_object are in this example? Also, why do we save twice in the second method? Thanks!:

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.article = self.object
        comment.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        article = self.get_object()
        return reverse("article_detail", kwargs={"pk": article.pk})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the book, but [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) will return the object that this view displays. In your example the view is probably set to display a single `Article`, but the form posts details for a `Comment`. You use the `get_object` method to get access to the `Article` instance so that you can associate the `Comment` with it.

Your second question: It doesn't save twice. It may be confusing, but when you set [`commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to `False` it instantiates the object, but does **not** save it. You do this when you want to add extra information after instantiating the model instance. It is actually saved to the database after the `comment.save()` call.